# PHP difference between echo 'string'.'\n'; and echo 'string'."\n";

Tags: php, escaping, echo, newline, quote

Given the following statements:

```
echo 'string1'."\n";
echo 'string2';
```

The following gets rendered as output:

```
string1
string2
```

With these statements

```
echo 'string1'.'\n';
echo 'string2';
```

This gets rendered (note the verbatim backslash *n*):

```
string1\nstring2
```

When `\n` is in double quotes, it makes a new line as it should.
when `\n` is in single quotes, it will be shown in the browser as text.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: So what is the question? You have answered.

Comment: A friendly reminder: There are 2 Answers to you Question, It's common courtesy to accept one of them :)

Answer (score 2):

Using single quotes will mark it as a string, so PHP will literally output `\n`.

See here: [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

---

Alternatively use [chr()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.chr.php) with the ASCII code of a new line as an argument:

```
echo 'string'.chr(10);
```

Or use the `<br/>` Tag

```
echo 'string<br/>';
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

*If the string is enclosed in double-quotes ("), PHP will interpret more escape sequences for special characters*